# Show application menus in top panel XFCE

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, panel, macosx

Hope you all doing well. My purpose is to have MacOS like application menu in xfce4 (Xubuntu 20). I mean this (I founded from the forum):

[image: Ubuntu macOS like top panel]

I googled a lot (even I searched a lot in this forum) and I couldn't find any way. However finally founded a plugin named "AppMenu", specially for xfce panel. Now when I use it, seems it works really great, but the main problem is application menus are still visible in their windows. Watch this:
[image]
So, I'm looking for a way to remove these menus from the all of applications or a better solution to have a MacOS like panel. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **Vala Panel Application Menu**, then [its documentation](https://github.com/rilian-la-te/vala-panel-appmenu#desktop-environment-specific-settings) says:

---

### Desktop Environment-Specific Settings

When using the Vala-panel-appmenu as an XFCE or MATE menu applet, you have to configure the appmenu to show in the panel applet, rather than on each individual window. This configuration should remove any 'double' menus you may experience:

**XFCE**

If you are using Vala-Panel-Appmenu for XFCE-Panel, type the following lines into your console:

```
xfconf-query -c xsettings -p /Gtk/ShellShowsMenubar -n -t bool -s true
xfconf-query -c xsettings -p /Gtk/ShellShowsAppmenu -n -t bool -s true
```